# ReactiveCrudRepository does not save objects in the database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I cant to save my object to Postgres.

My object User:

```
@Data
@Table("usr")
public class User {
  @Id
    private Long id;

    private LocalDate created;

    private LocalDate updated;

    private Status status;
    private String username;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    @Transient
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

My Table in Postgres:

```
create table usr (
    Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name CHARACTER VARYING(255),
     email CHARACTER VARYING(255),
    password CHARACTER VARYING(255),
    status CHARACTER VARYING(100) DEFAULT 'ACTIVE',
    created TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UNIQUE(Id)
);
```

My Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends ReactiveCrudRepository<User, Long> {
  //  Mono<User> findByName(String name);
}
```

I try to save User ->    `Mono<User> saveUser = userRepo.save(user);` but nothing work. I dont get any errors.

Comment: Questions on this site are required to be in English.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: "*but nothing work. I dont get any errors.*" I'm not sure we can help you in that case. If it doesn't work and doesn't produce any errors, you need to dig into it with a debugger to find out what's going on. Maybe you're swallowing an exception without logging it or something. Your code looks broadly right

Comment: Maybe needed to do an aditional actions with Mono<User> to complete save?

Comment: Did you (or something  like rest endpoint etc) subscribe to that reactive stream where the  repository.save was used? Reactive streams are lazy. Nothing happens until something subscribe to it.

Comment: @zlaval , Yes, you are right.  Added method subscribe for Mono<User> and saving completed. Thx